# How to cancel Update Manager downloading flashplugin-installer?

Tags: flash, update-manager, freeze

`Update Manger` has frozen for about 60min when downloading `flashplugin-installer`.
And the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button of `Applying Changes` dialog is disabled.
When I click the top-left <kbd>x</kbd>, it doesn't response.
How to cancel downloading `flashplugin-installer`?

```
...SKIP...
Setting up libxatracker1 (8.0.2-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up update-manager-core (1:0.156.14.5) ...
Setting up update-manager (1:0.156.14.5) ...
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.119ubuntu8.4) ...
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.236.orig.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't take much time to install flashplugin. To check whether update is still working (downloading/installing) check the output of this command: 
ps aux | grep http 
This will result in 2 or 3 lines with the second column of each line being the pid of the process if the process is doing its job. If the result is just 1 line, say the last phrase being grep http or something, the updates are not being downloaded/installed. Its safe to kill the update manager 
To do this: 
run: ps aux | grep update and note the pid of the update-manager being the second column after your user name in the 2/3 line list of output. Let the pid of update-manager be **pid** 
 
Kill this process by running: 
kill -9 **pid** 
If operation is not permitted, try with sudo, but take care that you don't kill any other process. Note the pid of update-manager carefully.

Answer (score 2):

The download will never start for many people, I knew it.

Something wrong as the server too slow or just not able to ping back.

See the **"featured/headline"** thread in [Ubuntuforums.org](http://forum.ubuntu.org.cn/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=387865&start=30) for instance.

Comment: I couldn't read chinese...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did (during a distribution upgrade, so it was critical):

First I found the stuck process (number 12123 in my case):

```
> pstree -p
├─gksu(7266)─┬─precise(9756)
│            ├─precise(9757)─┬dpkg(24158)─update-notifier(19121)─package-data-do(19123)
│            │               └{precise}(9759)
```

Then I helped out with bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/+bug/1243090 .
By running "sudo gdb" then "attach 19123" and "bt" to create a backtrace.  The backtrace helps the volunteers determine what's wrong.

Finally I used "sudo kill 19123" and received error message "Could not install 'update-notifier-common'" "subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 143".

The rest of the install then completed without incident. Dealing with flash can come another day.

Comment: Perfect - just saved me a lot of frustration!